# Mecurial, reverting to a revision where the subrepo didn't exist will trigger error

Tags: mercurial

I meet a problem with hg revert funtion.

> hg revert --all --rev "637f71e0714f59478b780cbfc98628d038d1bb80"
>
> abort: subrepository 'nested' does not exist in 637f71e0714f!

When I execute this command, an error is triggered because at revision 637f71e0714f sub-repository have not been created.

Do you know any option to bypass this error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I intend to use "hg update  --clean" If there is no workaround

Comment: Have you tried deleting the 'nested' subrepo folder from the working directory before doing the revert?

Comment: thanks Nanhydrin, but problem still occurs

Comment: Did you add the subrepo recently? If yes, and you are reverting the main repo to a revision which has files in the same directory, it will get confused. You need to (temporarly) remove/move the subrepo.